# One table for data fetched from multiple different third party apis or multiple tables per third party rest api endpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a requirement where I need to display to the user standardized data model that has 4 or 5 different pieces of information such as "Processing Fee", "Account Number", "Total Orders" etc. that can come from many different third party apis.
For example:
Warehouse A has an api that returns some JSON data
Warehouse B has an api that returns some JSON data

Both apis have differently formatted JSON responses however they both contain the data I need. They are just under different fields. It is possible however, that at some point in the future additional requests will have to be made to acquire required data from a given Warehouse api.

I need to store this data locally. Currently I do the following:

```
private async Task<Warehouse> GetWareHouseDataAsync(Warehouse warehouse, CancellationToken ct = default)
{   
    switch (Warehouse.ChainType)
    {
        case ChainType.UPS:
            {    
                RawUpsDataDTO rawUpsWarehouse = await _UpsWarehouseService.GetWarehouseDataAsync(warehouse.Id, ct);
                    
                Warehouse freshWareHouseData = WarehouseConverter.Convert(rawUpsWarehouse);                    
                return freshUpsWareHouseData;
            }
        case ChainType.Amazon:
            {
                ...
            }                    
        case ChainType.None:
        default:
           {
                ...
           }
    }
}
```

Where `Warehouse` is the standardized model for all apis.

Then I persist `Warehouse` to the database:

```
warehouse = await _warehouseRepository.AddAsync(warehouse, ct);
```

I am a little bit confused on trying to figure out which approach would be better suited:

A. Create separate database tables for the supported Warehouses
B. Create a single normalized database table (as it currently is) called something like 'WarehouseOperations' and just map the fields in the Convert method.

or any other approach that might be better?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, the implementation depends on what you are trying to achieve.

1. If you are trying to unify the data from multiple APIs, create models accordingly and make some mappers around each API (or use AutoMapper).
2. If you are trying to retrieve data as it is, try a top-bottom implementation for each API, and create API abstractions with a request-response pattern in mind.

If you want to cache data in a table, you should create a text column that will hold the data JSON serialized.

Caching the remote data needs to take into consideration some scenarios:

- how dynamic is the data from remote APIs
- when to invalidate the cache and retrieve the new data
- multi-cache distribution (in-memory + DB, or other combinations)

Let me know if you need more details. Happy coding!